# Click Event is fired multiple times at the same time

Tags: javascript, foreach

Within a click function, I have the below code:

```
home.addEventListener('click', () => {

       myAPP.mapview.map.layers.items.forEach(item => {
            item.visible = false;
        });
       //........... }
```

However, after the button is clicked once, it seems to continuously run/execute. How could I assure it executes, i.e. 'resets' just one time, just when the button or click function occurs?

Comment: Sharing your click function and perhaps markup would help. It's possibly a propagation issue where you need to stop the event from bubbling up. Will need to see the code to tell though

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that multiple dom elements are firing the same click event at the same time. You should have the following:

```
home.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // to prevent child/parent dom elements from firing the same event.
  if( e.target !== this ) {
    return;
  }
});
```